# google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-java with openjdk-11

Tags: linux, google-app-engine, apt

Is it possible to install app engine sdk over openjdk 11?

When I try it I get:

`$ sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-java`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-java : Depends: openjdk-7-jdk but it is not installable or
                                             openjdk-8-jdk but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

On my linux distro (Debian testing) openjdk-8-jdk is not available anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The App Engine SDK component for the Google Cloud SDK is currently not available for Java 11.

For reference, [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs) you have an installation guide for the Cloud SDK and its components. The link also contains a list of the Gcloud SDK additional components